# opencart - multistore and rewritebase

Tags: opencart, mod-rewrite

I have in my root web folder public_html/ installed my info webpage using rewrite rules (seo). In subfolder public_html/shop/ I have installed Opencart so the access to cart is http://www.mydomain.com/shop/. Each folder public_html, public_html_shop/ has own .htaccess file.

I would like to use OC1551 as multistore on several domains redirected to this folder, but also as www.mydomaincom/shop/ - not redirected: www.mydomain1.com, www.mydomain2.com and also as www.mydomain.com/shop/

*public_html/shop/.htaccess* file need to set rewritebase as /shop/ for properly working with info webpage, because use rewriting rules for www.mydomain.com/, but for www.mydoaminX.com need to be set as rewritebase / .
Can you pls someone help me with setting rewritebase in these folders to work it right? Something like dynamicaly changing rewritebase in public_html/shop/.htaccess file.

Thanks

**file public_html/.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.mydomain.sk/$0 [NC,L,R=301]

    RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)-([1-9])/(.*)/$ /index.php?category=$1&page=$2&gallery_page=$3&photo=$4 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ /index.php?category=$1&page=$2&photo=$3 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)-([1-9])/$ /index.php?category=$1&page=$2&gallery_page=$3 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$ /index.php?category=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /index.php?category=$1 [L,QSA]
    Rewriterule ^subscribe.php(.*)$ /index.php?category=overenie&addr=$1 [L,QSA]
    Rewriterule ^sitemap.xml$ /webmap.php?engine=google [L,QSA]
    Rewriterule ^urllist.txt$ /webmap.php?engine=yahoo [L,QSA]
```

**file public_html/shop/.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /shop/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^maydomain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.mydomain1.com/$0 [NC,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.mydomain2.com/$0 [NC,L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually find on the majority of servers that you can just remove the RewriteBase completely and it's smart enough to work out what it is. I would recommend trying this and seeing if it works